# Powershell Script Looping

Tags: windows, function, powershell, loops, scripting

I have a problem with this script which i cant seem to figure out. But everytime i run my getfirewall function, if i press Q at the beginning to quit, it still goes through the next questions about if i want to enable or disable it. And if i do Q again there, then it brings me to main menu. Then once in main menu, if i press q again to quit, it repeats itself making me type q again to quit.

```
function GetFirewall
{
    $choice18 = read-host "Please enter the computer you wish you get the firewall profiles from"
   
    do{ try{$s1 = New-PSSession -ComputerName $choice18 -Credential domain.com\user
             $success = $true}
        catch{Write-Output "Wrong Password, Next attempt in 5 seconds"
              Start-sleep -Seconds 5}
        $count++
        }until($count -eq 5 -or $success)
        if(-not($success)){Mainmenu}


    $firewallP = icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}
    $firewallP
    write-host "Domain(1)"
    write-host "Private(2)"
    write-host "Public(3)"
    write-host "All(4)"
    write-host "Quit(Q)"
    $choice19 = Read-host "Which do you want to modify or exit"
        
    write-host "Enable(1)"
    write-host "Disable(2)"
    $choice20 = read-host "Do you want to Enable or Disable the profile?"    
 
    switch($choice19)
    {

        1{ 
           Switch($choice20)
           {
                1{
                    icm -session $s1 -scriptblock{Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name "Domain" -Enabled True}
                    icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}
                 }
                2{
                    icm -session $s1 -scriptblock{Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name "Domain" -Enabled false}
                    icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}
                 }
           }
         }
        2{
            Switch($choice20)
           {
                1{
                    icm -session $s1 -scriptblock{Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name "Private" -Enabled True}
                    icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}
                  }
                2{
                    icm -session $s1 -scriptblock{Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name "Private" -Enabled false}
                    icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}
                 }
           } }
        3{
            Switch($choice20)
           {
                1{
                    icm -session $s1 -scriptblock{Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name "Public" -Enabled True}
                    icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}
                }
                2{
                    icm -session $s1 -scriptblock{Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name "Public" -Enabled false}
                    icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}
                 }
           } 
         }
        4{
            switch($choice20)
            {
            1{ 
                icm -session $s1 -scriptblock{Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled True}
                icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}}

            2{ 
                icm -session $s1 -scriptblock{Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False}
                icm -Session $s1 -scriptblock{Get-NetFirewallProfile -all |FT name, enabled}}
                   
            }
        }
        Q{Mainmenu}
    }
}
```

```
Function Mainmenu
{
Do {
    Write-Host "==========================="    
    Write-Host "        Main Menu          "
    Write-Host "==========================="    
    Write-Host "1: Active Directory Search"
    Write-Host "2: Service Administration"  
    Write-Host "3: Rename Remote PC"    
    Write-Host "4: Restart PC"
    Write-Host "5: Windows Update(Not Finished)"
    Write-Host "6: TestConnection"
    Write-Host "7: View Installed Apps(Almost Done)"
    Write-Host "8: View Firewall"
    Write-Host "Q: Quit"    
    Write-Host ''   
    $choice = Read-Host "Please select an option"   
    Switch ($choice) 
    {
        '1' 
        {       
            cls
            ActiveDirectoryInventory
        }
        '2' 
        {       
            cls
            Services
        }
        '3' 
        {
            cls
            RenamePC
        }
        '4' 
        {
            cls
            RestartPC
        }
        '5' 
        {
            cls
            WindowsUpdate
        }
        '6' 
        {
            cls
            Testconnect
        }
        '7'
        {
            cls
            GetApps
        }
        '8'
        {
            cls
            GetFirewall
        }
    }
}Until ($choice -eq 'Q')

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetFirewall` function is called *from* function `MainMenu`.

Therefore, simply *exit* your `GetFirewall` function when the user presses `Q`, and you'll return to the main menu.

Therefore, change `Q{Mainmenu}` to:

```
Q { return }
```

Note: Since your `switch` statement isn't followed by other statements in the function, `Q { break }` - which exits just the `switch` statement - would work too; `return` instantly exits the function as a whole.

This approach avoids bloating the call stack, which is what your current approach does (`MainMenu` calls `GetFirewall`, which calls `MainMenu` again, ...) and also avoids the problem of returning to `MainMenu` calls previously placed on the call stack.

Comment: Sweet, Thank you!! been bugging me for a while

Comment: @SteveG If you want additional "early exit" after the first question, it's as easy as adding `if($choice19 -eq 'Q'){ return }` on the line immediately below `$choice19 = Read-Host ...`

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @SteveG; allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment: